# Solving a partial ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have the following O.D.E.:
$$\frac{\Bbb dy}{\Bbb dx} = 2u.$$
Above, $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. My gut tells me that this equation is separable. In this way, do I have a “partial” integral? I have no idea how to solve this as $u$ is unknown and is also a function of $x$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If $u$ is a function of both $x$ and $y$, there's no reason for this to be separable.

Comment: What can I do then?

Comment: I don't think the problem is solvable except in special cases.

Comment: Your question is too broad. The equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=u(x,y)$ is the general form for an ODE. You can't say anything more. If $u(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ then it's a separable ODE which has a method of solution. There are no partial derivatives nor partial integrals involved here.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\Bbb dy}{\Bbb dx}=2u(x,y)=:F(x,y)\tag{1}$$
The above expression is the general form of a first-order O.D.E. There is no general solution to an arbitrary eqn. such as $(1)$ without given $F$ - however, there are theorems predicting the existence of solutions. Perhaps that’s what you’re looking for. Let me write one:

**Picard’s Theorem:** *Let $R$ be a rectangle, and suppose that $F(x,y)$ and $\partial F/\partial y$ are continuous on $R$. Also, suppose that $(x_0,y_0)$ is an interior point of $R$. Then, $(1)$ with the initial value $y(x_0)=y_0$ has a unique solution $y=y(x)$ for $x$ in some open interval $\mathcal{O}$ such that $x_0\in\mathcal{O}$.*

With the conditions of the above theorem, we see that any solution to $(1)$ with the initial value $y(x_0)=y_0$ must satisfy
$$y(x)=y_0+\int^x_{x_0}F\big(t,y(t)\big)\,\Bbb dt.$$
This, I guess, is the *“general” solution of $(1)$ with the initial value $y(x_0)=y_0$.*

Hope this helps.